# Stop asking location permission alert in Swift but need location

Tags: ios, swift

My app has different screen for allow location. So I don't want to ask location permission alert. Without asking alert Is there any way to allow location?

Comment: So you want access to location services *without* asking the user for permission?

Comment: Yes..Thanks for quick response

Comment: Think about it: What sense would it make that iOS has privacy settings if every app could choose to ignore them?

Comment: You must use the system location permission process - you cannot supply your own user interface for it.

Comment: @Paulw11 Do you have any link for that? So I can give it to the client

Comment: I am not aware of a link that explains what can't be done. The documentation for location services describes how the permission process works

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps that do not notify and obtain user consent before collecting, transmitting, or using location data will be rejected

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#location